# Using the results of WITH clause IN where STATEMENT of main query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, with-clause

I am relatively new at SQL so I apologise if this is obvious but I cannot work out how to use the results of the WITH clause query in the where statement of my main query.
My with query pulls the first record for each customer and gives the sale date for that record:

```
WITH summary AS(
SELECT ed2.customer,ed2.saledate,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ed2.customer
ORDER BY ed2.saledate)AS rk
FROM Filteredxportdocument ed2)
SELECT s.*
FROM summary s
WHERE s.rk=1
```

I need to use the date in the above query as the starting point and pull all records for each customer for their first 12 months i.e. where the sale date is between ed2.saledate AND ed2.saledate+12 months.
My main query is:

```
SELECT  ed.totalamountincvat, ed.saledate, ed.name AS SaleRef, 
ed.customer, ed.customername, comp.numberofemployees, 
comp.companyuid
FROM exportdocument AS ed INNER JOIN
FilteredAccount AS comp ON ed.customer = comp.accountid
WHERE (ed.statecode = 0)  AND
ed.saledate BETWEEN ed2.saledate AND DATEADD(M,12,ed2.saledate)
```

I am sure that I need to add the main query into the WITH clause but I cant work out where.  Is anyone able to help please

Comment: Perhaps you can create a view with the first query to reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
;WITH summary AS(
SELECT ed2.customer,ed2.saledate,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ed2.customer
ORDER BY ed2.saledate)AS rk
FROM Filteredxportdocument ed2)

SELECT  ed.totalamountincvat, ed.saledate, ed.name AS SaleRef, 
ed.customer, ed.customername, comp.numberofemployees, 
comp.companyuid
FROM exportdocument AS ed INNER JOIN
FilteredAccount AS comp ON ed.customer = comp.accountid
OUTER APPLY (SELECT s.* FROM summary s WHERE s.rk=1) ed2
WHERE ed.statecode = 0  AND
ed.saledate BETWEEN ed2.saledate AND DATEADD(M,12,ed2.saledate)
and ed.Customer = ed2.Customer
```

Results of `CTE` are not cached or stored, so you can't reuse it.

EDIT:

Based upon your requirement that all the records from CTE should be in final result, this is a new query:

```
;WITH summary AS(
SELECT ed2.customer,ed2.saledate,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ed2.customer
ORDER BY ed2.saledate)AS rk
FROM Filteredxportdocument ed2)

SELECT  
    ed.totalamountincvat, 
    ed.saledate, 
    ed.name AS SaleRef, 
    ed.customer, 
    ed.customername, 
    comp.numberofemployees, 
    comp.companyuid
FROM 
summary ed2 
left join exportdocument ed 
    on ed.Customer = ed2.Customer
    and ed.statecode = 0  
    AND ed.saledate BETWEEN ed2.saledate AND DATEADD(M,12,ed2.saledate)
INNER JOIN FilteredAccount comp 
    ON ed.customer = comp.accountid
WHERE 
     s.rk=1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the simple answer - and it works brilliantly

Comment: Unfortunately I am having a bit of a problem with what I thought was a working query.  When I use the query above I lose a huge percent of the companies that appear in the first query that I posted above.  It is obviously something to do with how they are put together.  Anyone have any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Can you remove the last line: `and ed.Customer = ed2.Customer` and try?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  will try that now and let you know

Comment: Not very successful unfortunately.  After running for 7 minutes with no results I felt that I had to stop the query as it was running on the live system and slowing it down.  If it helps all of the customers in the first query (WITH clause) should also be in the final results as they each have at least 1 sale that should be in the final set.  I tried using MIN to get the first sale but that did not pull all of the relevant records whereas the WITH clause does seem to work well.

Comment: Just wanted to note that I have found the problem with the report and it is not in the responses above but was an internal problem which has now been sorted.  This response works wonderfully well should anyone else need to do the same sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for letting know. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

summary you will be able to use only once. Alternate solution is store summary into temp table and use that as many times as u want.
Something like : Select * into #temp from Summary s where s.rk=1

Comment: Sorry to be a bit dim, but as I said I am new at this.  Are you saying that I should not put the queries above together as a single query?

Comment: have the data ready from the with clause in the first query, then in your main query you can use that dataset, but refrain from running the select clause after with, because the dataset you prepare through with clause can be used only once. Otherwise you can have the inner join in your main query with a temporary table, in that case you will be able to use the data at a later, as long as your session is active.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am struggling to follow.  As I said I am new at this and need the explanation to be a bit easier to follow.  An example would probably help somewhat.